# How to split a string into a Records in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a use case where I would like to split a string type into a Record.

Example:

```
const string = "Thank you"
```

And I would like to convert it into

```
Record<'Thank' | 'you', string>
```

Is there any easy way how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `const string` creates a constant variable called `string`, it's not a type. its type is string. You can't convert a runtime javascript variable to a static typescript type.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Sure you can.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You can construct new types from the type of a variable, sure. But you can't "convert" a runtime value to a static type.

Comment: @ShamPooSham A `const` declaration is a runtime value just as much as it is a static type, as demonstrated by the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [Template literal types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types)

```ts
const MY_STRING = "Thank you";
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] : [S];

type MY_STRING_PARTS_TUPLE = Split<typeof MY_STRING, ' '>
type MY_STRING_PARTS = MY_STRING_PARTS_TUPLE[number];
type MY_RECORD = Record<MY_STRING_PARTS, string>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTQPoGUAqAlAkgOQOIwC8MARGgBYCGYA1jAJ4gCuJA3AFBT0AOApjCm4AbAJZQAPChi8AHlF5gAJhBjQATiLABzADQwAItLkLlqqBu0A%20Iuxh2zFrUflKVUgPwPNWgNoBdGAAuW3spWRdTAHJImE9-IJC7MONXGAADABIAb00AM141GDQAX2z9UpywfMKAVWK02JgfND0AOnbBUQkavX1LAMCmlD8OTh5%20RFRMXDwkAAUAQQw0FCQ0GrmAGQBRIgFhMXEuPhBc%20GR0bHw9GMjLMb5zqavZxeWpYknLmfmllbWNjsfGAmABbABGBRGDwmyAw2wAwgB5DCGYgYXigNSKcRfab4X7vPTqbz3IA)

See also [Template literal types playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201028#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-bCgACyiBaRQAvpoB0OAaPpNPZ4PSMPQL0UIyp93QAB+euN-ugQST7AALjHE6KjmgS4vY-vjmuyEZl83r6ZU9Al+PiiCD4PAAwmQpDMLw1xSqYWYAlWPxTlqYAADLSGgyoSIYzCiIw3j5JiGCYLGTjOioWHetm6DMMwgqMK6VpoIE7QMG2HCYggGjnrsrFYpA56fEErwsIJ+xiJAfIKEohBgNx7HnoIsDqPQglkvgrwwlghjCVihzidYBCIaAKGkGgapOIQiDMp2WAYGUNgmo44BkpMCTCLwmZ4Bg9CHCSMa8PRfwAi+twnluxj4LsiAyIg0iSE2hatvUkGYpAOBDLsRloAAzGZgJoNgGiiLwTq5ZZ9DWbZ8COBgzpcNQOTGOQgTMJmnloE0mw8Ls6lWiVIJgjMASIOkfifKwZX5MO9pXGk5V3M47VtDwSL9DV1pVrs9DMBooBgbwJSMo49HkPlyCuOQ-lJt1TIxP+aL4DG6hpboSbgJMcopmmiA8PmhY5q9krSqQ1YGYSFJhqQ3q8DGnbZE2kqgMqAAMiMAKSOFQJC+E4vAUjdGI8Zxz1kqAABCiD0D9igk9QyBrAA0glcjyqmFrIJT2A5g8SqI5oqKuJoCqCwqDzA8M+KgAAEswcKFo4LPpjBI7qX6oB4QRjrkFWhD0hgjKxGUkOq1gJWsiUSKg2cQ2QF1BHKGU8AqCFn50g1lIzKAMY+Wgpuug8AAamgAJqaAAWg8jg63r-nGZw8jGfr227YTSbs8m2AAe98tfWziuc3zI4fKQvAh4orCF7wyIYNmIsGeMoAAErtK4GQUYzUwvIsMgg9ajEtVhhAybDyt26QDt0kU-IuwioCkdQHuIBRePZ26bYsE7B27KyJ5FGgpDUGQRB+CQdCELPdJkLwYbYJPV0lY56jOeYsC8NzquGqd+WXoPvHueY5O64Jag7EExiwMMsCQLw3Ylk6GvfKrxaCICyHqZgtpjJFwcBAIB2RzL5RqDIKijAYSIEdmvQUkBYC7AtJPYq-l8ogngF8JEEtFA+nMhAwMJpCaJmJnMKweZ2zlkrDMRwAARARnYhEllrLKQ8DYqziK7G9PcK9ZAAG0AC6P5ZFTAUYQb0UZlEaK0boRsOiywSJ7HONcAJwBTgHCIuxq51wAFUdz7lAKo8AjgcSaF4VgHMzjRHVk0ZeVRkx1EAG4DIZQRrEdoSA6FMDDFcWMmIMFwl9MoLGGRZCw0ZKkngigKhogoPlFqpJPRgDevlRidB0G9XdmvAMWBIidlAGIik-k4iYDvKQFARRzZEnCuLTA8cEQgkSfRR2sY0AUHAkyLWT0DAxNMoydo-JITOnkbjeQel0aOzWUQfkbZqp4IRCcf0MxdjnG8OYuIjBKgoJKtIEQvAqzLS2cwRwJ0zpQLbLGXAKgkS6muWQQ2V8b4aR2mUXSFyVEyCWWAZMmgEWAgpMfXi3CxSTHQvKPxyAcxVkcA8TQNdQHIVQqAbKhyNnEQadAik+xSRVU+aAH5bg+DkCZSQrB1sibYtMnil4nNw6PFJaLdKlKFTzzYRkO8CTozrN+FhEcWdvqKw+fSts+0wq7G7Ko3o+V8gYHYPccA6jVEiMgD06Q-TsAWsmNQCaJr7jOPUbuI67Y4wlUYsa01AAKcAABKGBrB6KbwwFKCCqToApQBMVCyp12KHVdnA7A1ByD4o1r1J1frQD+ucSGte4zXB8oMFaV00Ad4unIHadeTIbneywp2SpuwVpavqJtRO4FOhEHgNQOIJVukYF6XalN092VdBcOxR0zp0K7GyLIHqkcG1lGQNFO4-l5HXGGowea5kujYBkNQWNRd82TCDYiqYI6Z0YqxWgSY2UhV8IeKqDUxLxUGW1LbNlTcoIa0Pr8GQKU+Aq38pGSsHcGD3qmNK59-jX3qk0JlUVJKyW7G-T1K0FJ+RgRhNkegwHHBn3ulheAOE2pIN+PlcmnLGAZriFGqIABHagCg+Cb0gDCWdJUiAoOgBmrAjtv6EBoSJI0NJTiOC3t-QmIBdivFAKsdEtTCBBBpmgc0cYSmOxETELk-BFD8kxLsQwyBkCwHwOeEAsIFiKE0Hx6AwAvKkEzPQfkwBJAoFoMAZUmVEbKgAOyI2C2qAAbAAVhC8qAAnAADgVGFhUIwFNKbica0gs1VZok2kQE99pNCscUCoDM2QeA6cfIKBuKgyCmfM5Z6zwBbPmfs454Ad5BTYBq52SAmZPPrtOvgXz-mEuBbVGqQLMWAvIzVBFhUgXAspfFr0SAwRYYxkXgQM07AQgjvtH4W+rH2OOfmCQVAjBt2xjoFKUAuxaCr3E+IeRkmCARwZNdXB+QM2gEUxQGm0LeD5Uc6e+52XsC7CavQagPAbLkD43ECgVsQHyfFmZizVmQAyA0qCBzKDgAyEwqITAihgCIDhPgFBYlUDaVQLCpQyk7C7F2GsEcNHGD+VAs2w+p7eBZGYHIVIkg5NgDRw1kAcRMx85kFoO8wYKf5GQLjpzJp8AuWfqT0gYEM1EAsAz+IT83gKleMqV40JEDAFGNTg4tOXt6-wEAA)